# Pricing of Key Pairs and Security Groups on AWS?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, resources

My free AWS account expired. I deleted all S3 and EC2 resources, but am wandering if I can leave the `Key Pairs` and `Security Groups` without having to pay for them. (My account resources look like this now: [Resources](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5McUt95YdebXRmNmZxOWZhSHM/view?usp=sharing))

Amazon's documentation does not seem to mention this issue.

**Do these resources cost money?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There should be no charge for either of those things.

It's a bit of a stretch to call them "resources."  In the world of AWS, and in contrast to the other items on that list, those items are more like "metadata." (The same logic applies to Placement Groups.) You'll potentially need them if you launch future instances, but they aren't consuming anything resource-wise at AWS except for a tiny amount of storage, which isn't billable *to my knowledge* but I am unable to cite any authoritative documentation saying so.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. BTW, Re: "_my knowledge_" - seems I'm not the only one who couldn't determine Amazon's position on this point...

Comment: @user1656850 true enough, but I would suggest that the absence of documented charges also speaks fairly loudly, considering that AWS is not known for cramming undocumented, unexpected charges onto bills.  I didn't want to speak authoritatively without a citation to offer.

Answer (score 3):

You can See in your AWS Billing Dashboard There no Additional cost of securities group.

[image: Billing Details]

Answer (score -3):

Check out this like to AWS Pricing documentation relative to Key Management.
https://aws.amazon.com/kms/pricing/

It looks like AWS will charge $1 per month for each Key Pair.

Comment: KMS is a totally different system. EC2 key pairs and security groups don't cost a penny.